# lapply pdf output overwrites pdf instead of creating new ones

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I would be glad if someone could help me here. 
So, I am trying to use lapply for the secondary.peaks (sangeranalyserR package) function, however, I can not find a way to change the file.prefix to something that can change depending on the file. Here is what I am trying and failing.

```
lapply(list, secondary.peaks, output.folder = "/secondary_peaks",
   file.prefix = names(list))
```

So, basically the problem is in file.prefix, I want that for every file in the list uses the name of the list. The problem is when I make a list of names, it basically just take the first name and repeat it to every file in the list. Thus instead of end up with 5 files, with 5 names, I ended up with 1 file with the first name of the list names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` only iterates over the object given in its `X` argument. To iterate over multiple arguments, you need to use `mapply`.  Take note that the argument order in `mapply` is a little different.  I would try (untested)

```
mapply(FUN = secondary.peaks, 
       s = list, 
       file.prefix = names(list), 
       MoreArgs = list(output.folder = "/secondary_peaks"))
```

And if you want to be sure you get a list back as output, you can set `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` in the `mapply` call.  Make sure to read over the documentation for `mapply`.

Comment: It is the first question I posted here. I did not expect to find someone to help me that fast. It worked! Thank you a lot, you're awesome!!!!